# why my errors come first and print statements come second in python?

Tags: python, output

I wrote some classes which were a shopping cart, Customer, Order, and some functions for discounts for the orders. this is the final lines of my code.

```
anu = Customer('anu', 4500)  # 1
user_cart = [Lineitem('apple', 7, 7), Lineitem('orange', 5, 6)]  # 2
order1 = Order(anu, user_cart)  # 2
print(type(joe))  # 4
print(order1) # 5

format()  # 6
```

guys, I know that format throws an error for not passing any argument I am asking you why the error comes first and if it comes first how does the rest of the code execute well. I think the python interpreter keeps executing code and when it finds a bug it deletes all the output and throws that error. 
this is my output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\User\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/programming/python/progs/my_programs/abc_module/abstract_classes.py", line 97, in <module>
    format()
TypeError: format expected at least 1 argument, got 0
<class '__main__.Customer'>

Congratulations! your order was successfully processed.

Customer name: anu
Fidelity points: 4500 points

Order  :-
    product count: 2
        product        : apple
        amount         : 7 apple(s)
        price per unit : 7$ per 1 apple
        total price    : 49$


        product        : orange
        amount         : 5 orange(s)
        price per unit : 6$ per 1 orange
        total price    : 30$


subtotal        : 79$
promotion       : Fidelity Deal
discount amount : 24.88$
total           : 54.115$
```

Comment: What you're showing is not a [mcve]. The output doesn't come from the code you show, but from somewhere else. Take for example the line beginning with `Congratulations`, where do you print that?

Comment: the output does come from the code I just showed because of the `Order` class __repr__ magic method produces this output.  so when I print an object of the order class I can say it produces this output. so however I will reduce about fifteen lines of the output

Comment: How do you run your program? From inside an IDE? On the console?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I ran this on  Pycharm python Debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior happens because stdout is buffered and stderr is not, for performance reasons. It means that there can be delay when you write something on stdout (`print` instruction) but not when an error is written on stderr, hence resulting in stdout writing occuring after stderr.

See [this](https://eulertech.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/sys-out-flush-in-python/) for more details.

If you don't want this to happen, use:

```
python -u myscript.py
```

when calling your script. This has the effect of disabling the buffering of stdout.

EDIT: I see that you run on pycharm interpreter, in this case you can use the `-u` parameter for the python interpreter by adding the `-u` argument in the `run configuration` > `interpreter options` field.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm guessing right, your main question is about why part of the code seems to run before the error is detected? Then that's because Python is an *interpreted* language.

Besides pure syntactical errors which are detected when the file is loaded, all errors are detected when the Python interpreter is executing the statements.

That means the program will run until there's an actual error in it, so the code you have which does the initialization and printing will run because there's no error in it. Then the Python interpreter will detect the error that `format` doesn't have any arguments, and will report that error.

---

As for why the errors are printed first and your program output later, it's because errors and normal output are written to different "files". Errors are written to "standard error" (`stderr`) and normal output is written to "standard output" (`stdout`).

Your IDE catches output to `stderr` and `stdout` to different internal buffers, and simply seems to write output to `stderr` before it writes output to `stdout`.